# What is the function in Django that calls base.html and how can I see python code inside base.html execute at runtime

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, django

I'm not sure if its 2 questions, but I need to see the values of my python code being executed at runtime. Can anyone tell me how this works? Does the python get executed on the client side, and if so, how can I see its values like I can for my views classes in Eclipse?
I think I'm calling a js function that shows a calandar with custom python, but I'm not sure where it is so I can debug it. this is the call to the js in base.html

```
<script src="${url_static}js/jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="${url_static}js/admin/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){$('.datepicker').datepicker();});
    </script>
```

Comment: No, the Python gets executed on the server side of course. It *is* one of your view classes. But you have not shown any Python here, nor even anything that would call a view.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/ sorry i didn't know i had to... actually i think it is jquery-ui.min.js that is the problem coz when i check it on the client side it is an empty file...

Comment: oh you mean the serverside python view? nonono, i mean the python i being executed in the html files... how do i see THAT being executed?

Comment: What? There is no Python being "executed in the html files". Why do you think there is?

Comment: Are you talking about template tags or template rendering? They aren't executed in the html, by the time, they get to the client side they have been resolved into html

Answer (score 1):

Python code is executed on the server. The generated html is sent to the client. In the code you have posted {url_static} is meant to be replaced with the actual value, but probably doesn't work since django template looks for variables as `{{ url_static }}`. Notice the double braces.

Your datepicker isn't working since jquery isn't loaded. You can view source (or inspect element) for your rendered page and confirm if the script src is correct.

Comment: what is jquery? i thought it was just another name for javascript when it is querying something?

Comment: JQuery is a JavaScript library that has a lot of useful plugins such as the datepicker you are using (jquery.ui.datepicker-ja.js). You might want to look up about it if you're going to use it, but that's your choice.